# MYSQL Query - Checking result is true/false and count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check if the current user is already following the selected user, and I am doing this like so:

(I know it's not the best way, but as I am new to MYSQL this is as much as I have been able to come up with)

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Activity WHERE IdOtherUser = 86 AND id = 145)
```

I am '145' and the user I selected is '86'.

Now that return '0' If I am not following and '1' If I am following that person.

Seems to be working already but it definetly needs improving!

Now what I would like to do is count the followers in the same query.

So count the people I am following and the people following me.

'Activity' is the table where I store the followers and I save them like this:

'id' = me

'idOtherUser' = other user I followed

'type' = type of action "follow"

I have done count's before when calculating the like counts, but I just cannot get my head around this!!

If anyone could spare some time to help me it is much appreciated!

I am sorry if the question is not the best, but I am still learning and trying my best to format them as clear as possible to understand.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to count the followers from specific id from table Activity you might do this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(idOtherUser) AS "I Follow",
       (SELECT COUNT(idOtherUser) FROM Activity WHERE idOtherUser = 145 AND type = "follow"
) AS "FOLLOW ME",
       (SELECT COALESCE(id,0) FROM Activity WHERE IdOtherUser = 86 AND id = 145 AND type = "follow")
FROM Activity WHERE id = 145 AND type = "follow"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering.. That looks like what I want but I think there's some error.. I am getting #1630 - FUNCTION serverName.COUNT does not exist.

Comment: maybe because of the space can you try this:

Comment: SELECT COUNT(idOtherUser) AS "I Follow",
       (SELECT COUNT(idOtherUser) FROM Activity WHERE idOtherUser = 145 AND type = "follow"
) AS "FOLLOW ME"
FROM Activity WHERE id = 145 AND type = "follow"

Comment: Yeh that works nice, but how could I add the check which I added in my question above? Check if I am following this user I clicked on?

Comment: the query i gave list all the user based on the user id only. Do you mean from that list you want to check who is following you..?

Comment: No, what you gave me is good. It counts the users I am following and users that are following me. I need to check though if I am following the current user. So If I am user 145, and I select user 86 I want to see his followers/followings COUNT and then see If I(145) am following him

Comment: I updated my modification above. Added new select line to return 1 or 0 if a specific user is being followed.

Comment: Hey, getting this error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL(MAX(id),0) FROM Activity WHERE IdOtherUser = 86 AND id = 145 AND type = ' at line 4

Comment: apologies for the mistake I think I gave a sql query instead of mysql. Made modification please try again.

Comment: Same error again, can't figure what it is though...!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a "correlated subquery" to simplify the query and you `might` want distinct in the count also (depends on you data). I would avoid using spaces in column aliases too.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT A1.idOtherUser) as i_follow
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(DISTINCT A2.id)
            FROM Activity A2
            WHERE A2.idOtherUser = A1.id
                  AND A2.type = 'follow'
      )  as following_me
FROM Activity A1
WHERE A1.id = 145
      AND A1.idOtherUser = 86
      AND A1.type = 'follow'
```

Try it with distinct then without, if the result is the same leave distinct out of the query.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for that, sorry I only just saw your answer..Must of missed the notification! I tried It getting this error Unknown column 'a2.id' in 'field list'

Comment: My bad ignore above comment, didn't see the A so change a2 to A2...That works nice but I am also trying to check if the I am(145) following another selected user i.e 86

Comment: Basically I want to check if I am following the user I have selected, and also count the user's following/follower(like in the query you gave me)

Comment: Added an extra condition fot idotheruser is 86 and chand a2 to A2

Comment: I need another collumn though like the "i_follow" or "follow" which tell me's if I am following 86 or not.. Like with a 0 or 1. 1 for true obviously